# UIImages scroll like Instagram App

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am developing an app that presents to user a large number of images from a Instagram API. (1500 images).

I would reply Instagram Images Scroll. 
Is very important to support LARGE number of images.

Any help?

Thanks,

**EDIT:**
I use Lazy Load like: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: It is difficult to understand exactly what you are asking. Do you want to put those images in a UITableView? UIScrollView? Give us more information in order to help you.

Comment: I would like present a large number of images in a ScrollView without memory warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add a large amount of images in a UIScrollView you need to do a **lazy loading method**.
Which means to load the images at the same time you are scrolling. Also, to just have in the UIScrollView a small amount of images, not the whole array. For example the current one showing + the 3 before and the 3 after.

Here there is a good **example** to start with more information:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Here you can find a **project** using the same method too:

http://www.binpress.com/app/scroll-lazy-image-load-for-ios/907#description

Comment: Thanks men!!! I load images in `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`methods and no great user experience. :)